# Valums file uploader: how to start with ID other than 0?

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Andrew Valums' Ajax Upload plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) ([GitHub link](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader)). Here is some code from it:

```
qq.getUniqueId = (function(){
    var id = 0;
    return function(){ return id++; };
})();
```

It's kind of a long story, but I'm in a situation where, under certain circumstances, I'd like the `qq.getUniqueId` function to start with an ID other than 0. It can still increment by one; it just has to start with something other than 0. What's the best way to do that?

Here are the steps to create a test environment:

1. Download the plugin: http://github.com/valums/file-uploader/zipball/master
2. Unzip it and move the "client" folder onto a web server.
3. Open the "demo.htm" file in a text editor, search for `action: 'do-nothing.htm',` and add `onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {alert(id)},` right after that.
4. Open the "demo.htm" file in a web browser. Be sure to access it through a web server (as opposed to just opening the local file) or else it won't work.
5. Upload a file. It should alert a "0" after the upload finishes. See if you can modify it so that I can pass in a different starting number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the function with one that calls the original, but adds an offset:

```
function offsetUniqueId(n) {
   var old = qq.getUniqueId;
   qq.getUniqueId = function() {
       return old() + n;
   }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/gWjqX/

Comment: That certainly looks promising. Thanks! How would I pass a parameter in from the "demo.htm" file to tell the script to use a number other than 0? Like I said, it only has to be something else under certain circumstances.